# Getting 500 Internal Server Error when calling a WebMethod using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am having an issue hitting my C# WebMethod on the code behind and getting 500 internal server error. I don't really understand why it won't hit it so it would be really great if someone could tell me what is the problem.

[image]

So this is my ajax call and doesn't work even with data and datatype not commented out.

```
$('#chkBxAutoCost')
    .click(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:   "BatchReportCriteriaSelection.aspx/GetAutoJsonBatches",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "{}",
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus,    errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Request: " +
                        XMLHttpRequest.toString() +
                        "\n\nStatus: " +
                        textStatus +
                        "\n\nError: " +
                        errorThrown);
                },
                success: function() { console.log("success") }
            });
        }
    );
```

And this is my code behind method of the page:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetAutoJsonBatches()
{
    return autoJsonBatches;
}
```

So I have attached a breakpoint on this WebMethod and it's not being hit. I am pretty stuck so if someone had any insight I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 500 Internal Server Error while calling webmethod from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011998/asp-net-500-internal-server-error-while-calling-webmethod-from-javascript)

Comment: Try making your method `static`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011998/asp-net-500-internal-server-error-while-calling-webmethod-from-javascript

Comment: Thanks very much. Making it static fixed it. I've no way of accepting an answer from here though! If you add an answer below mine I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as botond said in the comments my problem was that webmethods need to be static! Thanks very much was really wrecking my head!

Answer (score 1):

First you have edit `RouteConfig.cs` and use

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

Next edit your `GetAutoJsonBatches()` to `static`

> They're static because they are entirely stateless, they don't create an instance of your page's class and nothing is passed to them
>   in the request (i.e. ViewState and form field values).
>
> HTTP is stateless by default, ASP.Net does a lot of stuff in the
>   background with ViewState, Session, etc. during a standard page
>   request to make life easier for developers.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463189/why-webmethod-declared-as-static)

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetAutoJsonBatches()
{
    return autoJsonBatches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, you need to use `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` attribute for your WebService.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetAutoJsonBatches()
    {
        return autoJsonBatches;
    }
}
```

And you haven't provided us what exactly is the exception message.