# Why occur Internal server error in my ajax query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, webmethod

I want to pass some value to server and it has to return one string.

**Jquery version**

```
 <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

Here is my code:

```
 $('#btnSaveFile').click(function () {
    var fileName = $('#txtFileName').val();
    alert(fileName);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ReportTotalSalesPivot.aspx/getFileExistOrNot',
        method: 'GET',      //method or type ?
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{fileName:' + fileName +'}',  //UPDATED Line
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            alert(data.d.exist);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('fail');
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

**Aspx code**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string getFileExistOrNot(string fileName)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQWebMatajer13"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select ReportData FROM [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[ReportSave] where Userfilename=@UserFileName  and ReportName=@ReportName";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserFileName", fileName);                
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportName", "TotalSales");
            con.Open();                
            var data = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (data != null)
            {
                string exist = "dataExist";
                return exist;
            }
            else
            {
                string exist = "notExist";
                return exist;
            }
        }            
    }
```

**Error Msg**
`GET http://localhost:55047/ReportTotalSalesPivot.aspx/getFileExistOrNot?fileName:www} 500 (Internal Server Error)`

> ExceptionType:"System.InvalidOperationException"
>
> Message:"An attempt was made to call the method 'getFileExistOrNot' using a GET request, which is not allowed."
>
> StackTrace:"   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)
> ↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)".

I think this error it occurs in server side. But I don't know what is that

**Updated**

> Error Message:"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:'fileName'."

Comment: Add [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)] to your C# method right below [WebMethod]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - using a POST request, which is not allowed Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883555/jquery-using-a-post-request-which-is-not-allowed-error)

Comment: Why negative marks. Tell me the proper reason.

Answer (score 2):

Send your **data** like below:

In object format

```
data: { fileName:fileName },
```

**OR**

As a String

```
data = "fileName="+filename;
```

Comment: try using `method:"POST"`.

Comment: try using like this in `url: 'ReportTotalSalesPivot.aspx/getFileExistOrNot?fileName='+fileName` and not need to send data seperately.,

Comment: No... Oh my God

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139411/discussion-between-mohamed-faiz-and-hek-mat).

Answer (score 0):

After one day I found What was my mistake.

This is the answer

```
data:'{fileName:"'+fileName+'"}'
```